# The $\mathrm{Hom}(E_2,E_1)$-action on $\mathrm{Ext}^1(E_2,E_1)$

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be objects in an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$. How can I see the natural action of $\mathrm{Hom}(E_2,E_1)$ on $\mathrm{Ext}^1(E_2,E_1)$?

Comment: I don't believe that there is such a natural action unless $E_1 = E_2$. What did you have in mind?

Comment: See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223996/how-do-we-get-the-quotient-ext1n-m-homn-m?rq=1